# CSS Image Gallery

Tags: html, css

My image gallery works fine when rolling over, although in the section where the images enlarge to, i'd like the first image in the gallery to automatically appear in there, at the moment it just displays a blank box until you hover over the image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"/>
<title>Welcome!</title>

</head>
<div id="wrapper">
<body>
<div id="header"> 
<div id ="logo">
<embed src="Media/Images/logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
</div>

<div id="icons">
    <img src="Media/Images/EnvelopeIcon.png" alt="Envelope Icon" height="25" width="30">
    <p>M015734a@student.staffs.ac.uk</p>
    <div class="clear">     
    </div>
    <img src="Media/Images/PhoneIcon.png" alt="Envelope Icon" height="25" width="30" />
    <p> 07904921417</p>
    <div class="clear">     
    </div>
    <img src="Media/Images/HouseIcon.png" alt="Envelope Icon" height="25" width="30">
        <p>Stafford, UK</p>
    <div class="clear">     
    </div>              
<div class="clear">     
</div>
</div>
</div>

<nav>
<div id ="NavBar">
     <div id="Nav1">
     <div id="Triangle1"></div>
    <a href="E:/Program%20Files/Dropbox/Corsair%20Backup/Media%20For%20The%20Web/Assignment%20Part%202/Index.html"><h2>About Me</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div id="Nav2">
    <div id="Triangle2"></div>
    <a href="E:/Program%20Files/Dropbox/Corsair%20Backup/Media%20For%20The%20Web/Assignment%20Part%202/Education.html"><h2>Education</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div id="Nav3">
    <div id="Triangle3"></div>
    <a href="E:/Program%20Files/Dropbox/Corsair%20Backup/Media%20For%20The%20Web/Assignment%20Part%202/Portfolio.html"><h2>Portfolio</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div id="Nav4">
    <div id="Triangle4"></div>
    <a href="E:/Program%20Files/Dropbox/Corsair%20Backup/Media%20For%20The%20Web/Assignment%20Part%202/Interests.html"><h2>Interests</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div id="Nav5">
    <div id="Triangle5"></div>
    <a href="E:/Program%20Files/Dropbox/Corsair%20Backup/Media%20For%20The%20Web/Assignment%20Part%202/Contact.html"><h2>Contact Me</h2></a>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
<article>
<section id = "content">
<h1>Portfolio Work</h1>
<div class="gallerycontainer">
<a class="thumbnail"><img src="Media/Images/Tardis.bmp" width="225px" height="125px" border="0" /><span><img src="Media/Images/Tardis.bmp" width="750px" height="450px"/><br />3DS Tardis Model.</span></a>
<br />
<a class="thumbnail"><img src="Media/Images/Main Station.png" width="225px" height="125px" border="0" /><span><img src="Media/Images/Main Station.png" width="750px" height="450px" /><br /></span></a>

<br />

<a class="thumbnail"><img src="Media/Images/Claymation1.JPG" width="225px" height="125px" border="0" /><span><img src="Media/Images/Claymation1.JPG" width="750px" height="450px"/><br />Sushi for dinner anyone?</span></a> 
<br/>

<a class="thumbnail"><img src="Media/Images/DSC_0245.jpg" width="175px" height="125px" border="0" /><span><img src="Media/Images/DSC_0245.jpg" width="500px" height="450px"/><br />Run wild with horses.</span></a>

<br />

<a class="thumbnail"><img src="Media/Images/DSC_0043 (3).JPG" width="225px" text-align="center" height="125px" border="0" /><span><img src="Media/Images/DSC_0043 (3).JPG" width="750px" height="450px"/><br />Run wild with horses.</span></a>

</div>
</section>
</section>
</article>
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
</body>
</html>


.gallerycontainer{
position: relative;
height: 250px;
/*Add a height attribute and set to largest image's height to prevent overlaying*/
}

.thumbnail img{
border: 1px solid white;
margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.thumbnail:hover{
background-color: transparent;
}

.thumbnail span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
position: absolute;
background-color: lightyellow;
padding: 5px;
left: -1000px;
visibility: hidden;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

.thumbnail span img{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
padding: 2px;
}

.thumbnail:hover span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
background-color: #333;
visibility: visible;
top: 0;
left: 250px; /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */
z-index: 50;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not hide the first image but give it a low z-index so the other images float over it. This will only work though if the images are the same dimensions.

HTML

```
<div class="gallerycontainer">
    <a class="thumbnail"><img src="Media/Images/Tardis.bmp" width="225px" height="125px" border="0" /><span class="first"><img src="Media/Images/Tardis.bmp" width="750px" height="450px"/><br />3DS Tardis Model.</span></a>
<br />
<a class="thumbnail"><img src="Media/Images/Main Station.png" width="225px" height="125px" border="0" /><span><img src="Media/Images/Main Station.png" width="750px" height="450px" /><br /></span></a>

<br />
```

CSS

```
.thumbnail:hover span, .thumbnail span.first{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
background-color: #FFF;
visibility: visible;
top: 0;
left: 250px; /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */
z-index: 50;
}

.thumbnail span.first
{
    z-index: 10 !important; /*Lower z-index for first one so others appear above it */
 }
```

**UPDATE**

From the code in your fiddle you've missed 2 important things in the implementing this:

1. Note the two selectors here (first line of my CSS code snippet): `.thumbnail:hover span, .thumbnail span.first`. You only have your original selector. -- this applies the same style to the "first" span as the "hovered" span
2. The leading  "." is missing in your code for `.thumbnail span.first` -- this adjusts the z-index for the "first" span so the others will appear above it.

**Update 2**

The span needs a background colour to mask the text of the first image. Also if the image has transparency, without the background color the first image will show though. The update fiddle shows this.

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5TmN/5/)

Comment: I've added that CSS in and the line for the <span class="first"> but i still can't get the first image to show in the space

Comment: add your code to jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) save it and post the url back here and I'll look further.

Comment: Too much code.... just post what is relevant to the issue. I've trimmed it down http://jsfiddle.net/t5TmN/1/ . I'll update my answer shortly. Images with absolute URLS would also be good see we can see them in the fidle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t5TmN/2/
Apologies for slow loading time on images, they need compressing still

Comment: Hi there, it works great!
However there is another issue, as my images have captions underneath them as the image switches, the text I type for the first image remains behind the other images at all times. Is there any fix for this?